# Python: Sort a list of objects based on their attributes

Tags: python, list, class, sorting

Just to preface this, I've already checked out posts pertaining to this question and they haven't fully answered mine.

So I would just like to know how to sort a list of objects based on their attributes in two ways:

1. if the attribute is a string (to alphabetize)
2. if the attribute is a integer (to do by numerical order)

This is my list of classes:

```
mainList = [
    hero( name='SirGoose', classes='Fighter', level=150 ),
    hero( name='Conan', classes='Barbarian', level=160 ),
    hero( name='KingArthur', classes='Knight', level=170 )
]
```

So what I'm really looking for is a way to sort this list to that the hero's names are sorted in alphabetical order, then another method for level. Thank you!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`sorted`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sorted), [`list.sort`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#list.sort) accept optional `key` parameter. Pass a key function. The return value of the function is used for comparison instead of the original value:

```
>>> from collections import namedtuple
>>> hero = namedtuple('hero', ['name', 'classes', 'level'])
>>>
>>> mainList = [
...     hero(name='SirGoose', classes='Fighter', level=150 ),
...     hero(name='Conan', classes='Barbarian', level=160 ),
...     hero( name='KingArthur', classes='Knight', level=170 )
... ]
>>> sorted(mainList, key=lambda h: (h.name, h.level))
[hero(name='Conan', classes='Barbarian', level=160),
 hero(name='KingArthur', classes='Knight', level=170),
 hero(name='SirGoose', classes='Fighter', level=150)]
```

NOTE: the key function used here (`lambda`) returns a tuple. tuples are compared item by item. If the first items are same, the next items are compared, ...

```
>>> ('SirGoose', 12) < ('Barbarian', 160)
False
>>> ('SirGoose', 12) < ('SirGoose', 160)
True
```

---

Alternative using [`operator.attrgetter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.attrgetter):

```
>>> import operator
>>> sorted(mainList, key=operator.attrgetter('name', 'level'))
[hero(name='Conan', classes='Barbarian', level=160),
 hero(name='KingArthur', classes='Knight', level=170),
 hero(name='SirGoose', classes='Fighter', level=150)]
```